# ListView List position is over an EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, xamarin, android-edittext

In Xamarin, I have an EditText object, and a ListView that is populated with items when text is entered into the EditText object.

Currently, when I type text into the EditText, the ListView is displayed, but is over top of the EditText, such that I cannot enter in any more data.

How can I display the ListView under the EditText object?

Here is my Layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/List"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="281.5dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:hint="Find..."
        android:layout_marginBottom="15.2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8.5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you set the orientation of relative layout? tell me this first.

Comment: Relative Layout doesn't need orientation.

Comment: what is android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/List"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="281.5dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:hint="Find..."
        android:layout_marginBottom="15.2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8.5dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/List"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/tr" />
<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tr">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="281.5dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:hint="Find..."
    android:layout_marginBottom="15.2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8.5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8.5dp" />
</TableRow>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Try this one, hope it will help you..

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:padding="5dip">


    <EditText
      android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
      android:layout_width="281.5dp"
      android:layout_height="45dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="15.2dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8.5dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8.5dp"
      android:hint="Find..." />

   <ListView
      android:id="@+id/List"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_below="@+id/inputSearch" />


</RelativeLayout>
```